# wxPython Browser Size

Tags: python, webview, wxpython

Why does the following code create a browser object the takes up the entire window? I want the browser object to only take up a certain amount of space, like a textbox or button in wx would.

```
import wx
import wx.html2

app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, "yo", (1,1), (800,600))
browser = wx.html2.WebView.New(frame, -1, "http://www.google.com/", (0,50), (500,500))
browser.LoadURL("http://www.google.ca")
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Feature of wxFrame is that if it has only one child window the frame's EVT_SIZE handler will automatically size and position it such that it fills the client area of the frame.  If you want to prevent that or to have some other sizing behavior then you can implement your own EVT_SIZE event handler for the frame.  Other options are to use a wx.Sizer or, as has already been suggested, use a wx.Panel as the only child of the frame and make the WebView be a child of the panel.

Answer (score 0):

Put the browser into a panel, and put the panel in the frame (parent). The browser will use the entire panel.

```
panel = wx.Panel(frame, -1, (100,100), (100,100))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
import wx
import wx.html2


class MyWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, url, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        label = wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Hi, this is a label")
        sizer.Add(label)
        browser = wx.html2.WebView.New(self, wx.ID_ANY, url, (0, 50), (500, 500))
        sizer.Add(browser)
        browser.LoadURL(url)


app = wx.App()
frame = MyWindow("http://www.google.com/", None, wx.ID_ANY,
                 "yo", (1, 1), (800, 600))
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```